# protobuf data to avro in python

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, apache-beam, avro

I have data which is in protobuf format and im able to parse read,convert to json,dict in python, but i want to convert it to avro. How should i do

```
import time
import sys

import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
import csv
import base64
from google.protobuf import timestamp_pb2
from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToDict
from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToJson

 import io

 import logging

 from google.cloud import storage
 import json
 from otherfiles import protobuff_pb2

 b64ProtoData = "proto formated data"

 b64ProtoData = b64ProtoData.replace('_', '/')
        b64ProtoData = b64ProtoData.replace('*', '=')
        b64ProtoData = b64ProtoData.replace('-', '+')
        finalbunary = base64.b64decode(b64ProtoData)
        log = protobuff_pb2.ProcessorLogProto()
        log.ParseFromString(finalbunary)
        jsonObj = MessageToJson(log)
```

Comment: What have you tried? There is the python library `avro` and `fastavro` that can be used to create the avro format.

Comment: @Scott gone through fastavro, but not sure, how to convert from above code and schema should be dynamic, if you have  something i can try , let me know, thanks in advance

Comment: Actually i want to load protobuff data into bigquery, but dont have ideas for that as well, so trying things like this, protobuff to json then to bq or protobuf to avro then bq

Comment: @chethi were you able to solve this piece I am trying to read a protobuf and then convert it into avro

Comment: @ankushreddy , directly from proto to avro not able to solve , but i did it like this for testin proto to json record and then json record to avro, but i will not recomend this.